# Integral of random variable over a random time interval

Tags: probability, integration, random-variables

In a lecture on stochastic processes, I saw the following.

For a Poisson process with (iid Exp($\lambda$)) interarrival times $(X_n)_{n\geq1}$ and arrival times $(S_n)_{n\geq0}$ with $S_0=0$, we have the following
$$
\int_{S_n}^{S_{n+1}} X_{n+1} ds = \int_0^{X_1} X_1 ds = X_1 \cdot X_1.
$$

What is the reasoning for this? Also, is there a good reference that explains (1) integrals of RVs with fixed bounds of integration, (2) integration of functions over random intervals, and (3) integration of random variables over random bounds of integration?

Answer (score 0):

To integrate over an interval is to integrate over the indicator function of the interval.  A random indicator function is just another random variable, which we can integrate.

The equality between the first quantity and the second follows from iid and setting n to 0.  The equality between the second quantity and the third can be understood as a realisation-by-realisation fact.  For each realisation, the random variable is a constant independent of s, and can be pulled out of the integral.